# Pirates and resources; beautiful linear algebra rounding

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I saw the following riddles:
Given $n$ boxes, the ith box contains $k$ numbers/resources: $a_{1,i},a_{2,i}..,a_{k,i}$. Prove we can pick (for large enough $n$) at most $k+\bigl[\frac{n-k}{2}\bigr]$ boxes, where $[]$ is the floor function, such that those boxes contain at least half of each resource in total.
 More generally, if instead of one half we want $\frac{p}{q}$, we need $k+\bigl[\frac{pn-k}{q}\bigr]$ boxes.

I am able to get (won't get the exact expression since it's not good enough anyway) $\bigl[\frac{n}{2}\bigr]+k+1$ by an argument similiar to Beck Fiala theorem (give coefficients $\frac{1}{2}$ to all boxes at first, and then take a linear combinatoin that preserves the sum of the coefficients, and the amount of each resource, add a multiple of it to our current solution until one of the variables becomes $0$ or $1$. Throw it out, and repeat. We get stuck when we have $k+1$ or less boxes, at which point we take all of them).

This method seems to not be able to get over that bound, because if at the end we have small coefficients for $k$ boxes, each of which is just full of one resource, it's problematic.